# LINQ Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

Tags: c#, linq

I hardly used LINQ in the past. When I tried to compose a little LINQ query today using LinqPad, then I got the following error:

`Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'`

This is the script I was trying to write:

```
void Main()
{
            var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");
            var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());
            var csvData = csvLinesData.Where(l => (!l[12].Contains("VM") && l[12] != "Voice Mail")).ToArray();
            var user = (from r in csvData
                        orderby r[12]
                        select new User
                        {
                            CSRName = r[12],

                            Incomming = (from r1 in r
                                         where r1[4] == "I"
                                         select r1).Count(),
                            outgoing = (from r1 in r
                                        where r1[4] == "O"
                                        select r1).Count()



                        }).ToList();
                        user.Dump();
}

class User
{
    public string CSRName;
    public int Outgoing;
    public int Incomming;
    public int calltransfer;
}
```

### EDIT 1

As per suggestion I edited the code

```
                    select new User 
                    {
                        CSRName=r[12],
                        Incomming=(from r1 in r
                                  where r1[4]=='I'
                                  select r1).Count(),
                        outgoing = (from r1 in r
                                    where r1[4] == 'O'
                                    select r1).Count()

                    }).ToList();
```

Now it compiles, but it is throwing a different error:

`IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Where I am making the mistake ?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised it doesn't convert it for you, but does it work if you just do `r1[4] == 'I'` and `r1[4] == 'O'` (single quotes instead of double quotes)?

Comment: please see my edited portion because i am getting different error now. thanks

Comment: you're trying to access the 13th (`r1[12]`) and 5th (`r1[4]` characters in `r1`. It appears that at least one value of r1 isn't that long. You need to handle that scenario.

Comment: how to capture and handle the situation?

Comment: Use debugger. Set breakpoint in the place where you create the array, and follow step by step (F10) and watch how the lenght change...

Comment: Why is this being voted down so much...? looks ok to me...

Comment: Because the question is different topic and title now... Error has nothing to do with char or string....

Comment: @BG100 just see i just asked a question and people start giving negative vote for no reason.......because people has to pay nothing to give down vote.

Comment: @Thomas - it's because this question has been asked many times before. I can take your title and put it into Google and literally get loads of places to find the answer. Also, your question has been answered by fubo. You should mark his as correct, then if you still need your next error sorting (although it's been explained in comments) ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: i just post a new thread where i explain what i am trying to do in detail. here is url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894866/how-to-query-and-extact-data-from-csv-file-directly-by-linq   please have a look and answer in details. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're comparing string and char type

replace

`where r1[4] == "I"` /  `where r1[4] == "O"`

with

`where r1[4] == 'I'` /  `where r1[4] == 'O'`

Comment: please see my edited portion because i am getting different error now. thanks

Comment: your at least one of your indexes seems to be invalid / to high `r1[4]`, `l[12]` or `r[12]` time for debugging

Comment: how to capture and handle the situation?

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes to refer to 'char':

```
Incomming = (from r1 in r
    where r1[4] == 'I'
    select r1).Count(),
    outgoing = (from r1 in r
        where r1[4] == 'O'
        select r1).Count()
```

Comment: please see my edited portion because i am getting different error now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw that the **1st error** is already solved (use `'` quotes instead of `"` to enclose characters).

Regarding your **2nd error** ("Edit 1" in your question): From your code I assume that `r1` is a character array.

You are reading from a comma-separated text file ("*.CSV-file"):

```
var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");
```

While the columns are comma-separated, this format does not enforce you have the same number of columns in each row. A new row begins if you have terminated the line with CR+LF.

But in the source you've provided you're assuming that every row  (`r1`) in your `*.CSV` file needs to contain 5 characters, which is not always the case.

Hence in those cases the dimension of the character array `r1` is shorter and you're getting

`IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

if you're trying to access `r1[4]`.

To illustrate this, I am giving an

**Example:**

```
char[] r = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
Console.WriteLine(r[2]); // succeeds
Console.WriteLine(r[3]); // succeeds
Console.WriteLine(r[4]); // fails: allowed index range is 0..3
```

Use `r.Length` to get the length of the array: In the example it is 4, and the index starts with 0, hence the allowed range is 0..3.

Change your code accordingly, for example:

`where (r1!=null && r1.Length>=5) && (r1[4] == 'O')`

to ensure it does not get outside of the bounds of the array. You can easily test that in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) (or put the code below into the Main function of a console application to test it, [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) will also run it nicely):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            var r = new List<char[]> { new char[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }, 
                new char[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'O' } };

            Console.WriteLine((from r1 in r
            where (r1!=null && r1.Length>=5) && r1[4] == 'O'
            select r1).Count());
    }

}
```

If you remove the expression `(r1!=null && r1.Length>=5)` then the error you have mentioned occurs.